# Before inserting new element in xml check if exists the value

Tags: c#, xml

I have below a xml file with the below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
<Countries>
    <country>India</country>
    <country>USA</country>  
    <country>UK</country>      
</Countries>
</Root>

string newCountry="UAE"
```

I want to insert this "UAE" country to the above xml file, before that I want to check whether "UAE" is already exists in the xml. If not exists then only want to insert otherwise no operation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("path_to_file");
string newCountry = "UAE";

XElement countries = xml.Descendants("Countries").First();
XElement el = countries.Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == newCountry);
if (el == null)
{
    el = new XElement("country");
    el.Value = newCountry;
    countries.Add(el);        
}

//Console.WriteLine(countries.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks, it works. need to call Countries.Save("path to xml") method to update the xml.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to read the xml into C# objects, check for the existance of UAE, potentially add it, and write the objects back to XML.